# Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~7.2.2 Found invalid: @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4

Tags: android, expo, mobile-development

I updated my expo sdk to 49 and now I'm unable to create android build. I've been on this for a week now and couldn't find any good solution to it.

My current package is : `"@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",`

```
Expected package @expo/config-plugins@~7.2.2
Found invalid:
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
  @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
```

After running this command `npm why @expo/config-plugins` it shows me this :

```
    @expo/config-plugins@7.2.2
node_modules/@expo/config-plugins
  @expo/config-plugins@"7.2.2" from the root project

@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
node_modules/expo/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins

@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
node_modules/expo-updates/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins

@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
node_modules/@expo/cli/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins

@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
node_modules/@expo/config/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins

@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4
node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins
```

Has anyone already fixed this kind of issue? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I had several problems when I updated one of my projects. have you tried this? 
 npx expo install --fix
more information please

Comment: Yeah I did and it started creating builds for ios. But then android builds started failing.

Comment: I have a suggestion but please keep a backup before doing this,

 uninstall @expo/config-plugins and check node_modules to be sure that this folder is removed.

Remove webpack and webpack config and use the Metro. 

npx expo install --fix
npx expo start --clear

Answer (score 1):

**I RESOLVED this issue just now**

- Simply removed the ~ from `~7.2.2`
- Removed `expo-modules-autolinking`
- Deleted yarn.lock file and reinstalled it using `yarn`
- Update expo sdk to latest i.e. `49.0.13` by running `npm install expo@latest`

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add some resolutions in my package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.2.4",
    "@expo/metro-config": "~0.10.0",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.5.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On checking my `yarn.lock` file, I found out that packages `@react-native-firebase/analytics` and such were requiring the `@expo/config-plugins@5.0.4` dependencies.
So, I upgraded all the `@react-native-firebase/...` packages and the issue with `config-plugin` was gone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, running `npm why @expo/config-plugins` showed a list of packages that depend on config-plugins, where I identified `expo-google-sign-in@11.0.0` as the source of the conflicting version of `@expo/config-plugins`. Removing `expo-google-sign-in@11.0.0` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I lost a day or two on this and nothing was helping, and then I went again through all the old commits and I tried to remove all the new packages one by one and the one that finally solved it for me is removing expo module scripts:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@types/react": "~18.2.14",
"@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
"expo-module-scripts": "^3.4.1",
"typescript": "^5.1.3"
},
```

So basically running npm uninstall expo-module-scripts solved it for me.